# Error in eclipse project grails/groovy

Tags: eclipse, grails

I have the following error when working with grails project in eclipse

> An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
>   org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core.compiler.GroovySnippetCompiler.(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/core/model/GroovyProjectFacade;)V

Anybody have the same problem?

How fix the problem?

Comment: What versions are you using for Eclipse and Groovy Eclipse? Also, if there was a stack trace following the error shown in the OP please include it.

Comment: Eclipse neon package 3, and this groovy plugin http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.6/. I follow this tutorial: https://technology.first8.nl/eclipse-neon-grails-2-x-with-groovy-and-gsp-support/

Comment: @MisterB are you using Grails 2.x or Grails 3.x?

Comment: My version is Grails 2.2.5

Comment: Do you have Grails tooling added to Eclipse?  It would be helpful for you to go to Installation Details and share a snapshot of all the features you have added to Eclipse.  And you need to describe what actions you are taking with your grails project.  "Working with a grails project" is to general to be useful.  And please as @skomisa said, include the stack trace with the error message.  GroovyProjectFacade was moved recently, so there may be an issue with an incompatible plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

The issue was fixed in the latest Snapshot releases of Groovy Eclipse 2.9.3 so you may now just follow the guide @ https://technology.first8.nl/eclipse-neon-grails-2-x-with-groovy-and-gsp-support/

**Previous answer**:

I also stumbled across this error and it happens only in classes that are grails-artefacts (services, controllers, ...). It seems to be related to recent changes in grails-eclipse plugin 2.9.2. A version from june 2017 worked without any issues and a recent upgrade to 2.9.2 release from january 2018 brought up the issue.

I fixed the issue by using the groovy-eclipse 2.9.2 version from 2015 which is contained in the GGTS update-site zip (http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.6.4.RELEASE/e4.5/springsource-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.5-updatesite.zip).

What I was searching for (without success) was an archive of release versions of the groovy-eclipse 2.9.2 branch. This way I would at least have the option to install the working 2.9.2 version from june 2017... If anyone has a clue where to find older versions I would be happy for a hint!

The stacktrace of the initially mentioned Exception looks like that:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core.compiler.GroovySnippetCompiler.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/core/model/GroovyProjectFacade;)V
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.types.PerProjectTypeCache.setProject(PerProjectTypeCache.java:107)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.GrailsCore$PerProjectCacheManager.get(GrailsCore.java:54)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.GrailsCore.connect(GrailsCore.java:199)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.elements.GrailsProject.findAllServices(GrailsProject.java:510)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.types.PerProjectServiceCache.ensureInitialized(PerProjectServiceCache.java:108)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.types.PerProjectServiceCache.findServicesFor(PerProjectServiceCache.java:93)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.elements.AbstractGrailsElement.populateInjectedServices(AbstractGrailsElement.java:148)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.elements.ControllerClass.initializeTypeLookup(ControllerClass.java:284)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.groovy.types.GrailsTypeLookup.initialize(GrailsTypeLookup.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.search.TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.visitCompilationUnit(TypeInferencingVisitorWithRequestor.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codebrowsing.requestor.CodeSelectHelper.selectASTNode(CodeSelectHelper.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.search.GroovyOccurrencesFinder.initialize(GroovyOccurrencesFinder.java:181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.search.GroovyOccurrencesFinder.findOccurrences(GroovyOccurrencesFinder.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.GroovyEditor.updateOccurrenceAnnotations(GroovyEditor.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor$6.selectionChanged(JavaEditor.java:3380)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$3.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: I can fix this for the 2.9.3 snapshots.  Could you submit an issue to https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues?

Comment: I'll do, thank you. Maybe you can point me to an update-site archive where I may download previous releases?

Comment: Hi @ClemensSum, Can you solve this problem? How steps are necessary to fix?

Comment: As @emilles fixed the issue in 2.9.3 snapshots of Groovy Eclipse, you may now follow the guide @ https://technology.first8.nl/eclipse-neon-grails-2-x-with-groovy-and-gsp-support/ and it should all work out as expected.